# Any hints for analysing $\prod_{i=1}^n\big(1 + \alpha(-1)^i/\sqrt i\big)$?

Tags: optimization, asymptotics, generating-functions, products

The context is analysing the behaviour of the Prod algorithm under a certain input.
I have two products

$$W_1^n = \prod_{i=1}^n\left(1 + \frac{\alpha(-1)^i}{ \sqrt i}\right) \qquad \qquad \qquad W_2^n = \prod_{i=1}^n\left(1 + \frac{\alpha(-1)^i}{ i}\right)$$

for some $\alpha < 1$. These are used to construct the point $\frac{(W_1,W_2)}{W_1+W_2}$ in the simplex.

I don't know much about analysing products in the first place. Are there any obvious tips or tricks that look useful for the following problem?

[If I plot the products](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hsgth6t0a9) it looks like both converge to some $W_1^n \to W_1$  and $W_2^n \to W_2$ as $n \to \infty$. Moreover the sign changes ensures that $W_1^n$ is alternately greater and less than the limit. I am interested in bounding from below the size  $|W_1^n - W_1|$ and $|W_2^n - W_2|$ of these oscillations. Experimentally it seems they have size $O(1/\sqrt n)$ and I would like to prove that.

It is believable we could estimate $W_1^n$ as follows: $(1)$ Expand log $W_1^n$ as a sum. $(2)$ Separate the positive and negative parts of the sum. $(3)$ Use convexity to bound the positive and negative parts from both sizes. $(4)$ Replace the resulting  sums over $1/\sqrt n$ or $1/n$ with integrals. $(5)$ use the integrals to estimate the sums from both sides.

However this sounds like an awful lot of work and might not be helpful if the errors in the estimate are larger than the size of the oscillations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2k-1}\right)\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{2k}\right)=1-\frac{\alpha(1+\alpha)}{2k(2k-1)}$$ easily implies that $W_2$ converges (and the bounds are easier to obtain just this way, i.e. not by *separating* the parts, but by estimating the product of *even* (or odd) number of terms, and adding the extra term if any).

But for $$a_k:=\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2k-1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2k}}\right)=1-\frac{\alpha(\alpha+\sqrt{2k}-\sqrt{2k-1})}{\sqrt{2k(2k-1)}}$$ we have $k(1-a_k)\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\alpha^2/2$, thus $W_1$ diverges (to zero) if $\alpha\neq 0$.

A side note. $W_2$ can be computed using the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass%27s_definition): $$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{\alpha(-1)^k}{k}\right)=\frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{\alpha}{2k})\exp(-\frac{\alpha}{2k})\right)^2}{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{\alpha}{k})\exp(-\frac{\alpha}{k})}=\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\Gamma^2(1+\alpha/2)}=\ldots$$

Comment: Is there an elementary way to see for $b \le 1$ that $\prod(1 - b/n) \to 0$ but $\prod(1 - b/n^2)\ge \epsilon > 0$. is ? For $b =1$. For $b=1$ I can compute the sums directly but replacing $1$ with $b$ makes things harder.

Comment: I can show the first product goes to zero using logs.

Comment: @Daron: It's basically $1-\sum_n a_n\leq\prod_n(1-a_n)\leq\exp(-\sum_n a_n)$ if $0\leq a_n\leq 1$. For ($0<b<1$ and) $a_n=b/n$ we use the upper bound and the divergence of $\sum_n 1/n$, and for $a_n=b/n^2$ we take a tail of $\sum_n 1/n^2$ and use the lower bound. Pretty standard.

Comment: Well it may be standard stuff, but it's new to me so thanks a million! Does the first part $1-\sum a_n \le \prod (1-a_n)$ have a name or perhaps a one word hint at the proof?

Comment: @Daron: Induction. (I didn't see it named.)

Comment: Thanks. It looked a bit like a logs + convexity result to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it diverges to zero.

If you take the log, the first two terms give
$\sum (-1)^n a/\sqrt{n}
$
and
$\sum  a/n
$
with other sums of these forms
with higher powers of $n$.

The first sum converges by the alternating series test,
and the latter ones by comparison with
$1/n^{c}$
with $c > 1$.

The second sum diverges
(harmonic sum)
so the overall sums diverge.